# HTML sent via PHP mail() function not showing correctly in mail

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, html-email

I have set up a `mail()` function that's pretty straight forward in `PHP`:

```
$to = $_POST['address_to_send'];
$subject = "New Message";
$message = $_POST['content_to_send'];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: me@example.com" . "\r\n";

echo $message;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

The `echo` shows my lovely formatted `HTML` exactly the way I want it and it sends the email as expected to the correct address with the correct subject and the correct from address.

However, the actual content of the email is blank.

The content is being generated using `PHP` but do not think this should make a difference, as the `echo` is showing just the HTML formatted correctly.

### Edit

After testing, the `echo` only works locally on WAMP and not live on my server.

Tried using a `var_dump()` instead to try figure out what was going on and although in WAMP it gives me my string it is empty when it's live on the server.

So I think it is to do with how I'm firing the mail function.

I have a form like so (generated in `PHP`):

```
<form action='purchase_orders.php?id=$order_id' method='POST'>
<button onclick='send_po($i)'>Send to $email</button><br />
<input type='hidden' id='po_content_to_send' name='po_content_to_send'>
<input type='hidden' id='po_address_to_send' name='po_address_to_send' value='$email'>
</form>
```

This fires the following function in `JS`:

```
function send_po(po){
    var po_to_send = document.getElementById('purchase_order_'+po).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('po_content_to_send').value = po_to_send;
    this.form.submit();
}
```

This adds the content of the DIV in question to the hidden input before submitting the form which should trigger this `PHP`:

```
if(isset($_POST['po_content_to_send']) && isset($_POST['po_address_to_send'])){
    $to = $_POST['po_address_to_send'];
    $subject = "New Purchase Order";
    $message = $_POST['po_content_to_send'];
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: me@example.com" . "\r\n";
    var_dump($message);
    //mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your message?

Comment: Tryied to send mail from your script like: `<table><tr><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr></table>` it works OK! I think problem in your `$message`

Comment: I'd recommend using PHPMailer, that you tagged this question with. It encodes message bodies correctly. The script in your question is a spam gateway, and can be abused by spammers to send unlimited amounts of email to anyone from *your* server. Don't do that.

Comment: There is a whole catalog of issues with this code. You are not producing a mime formatted email. You are not producing an SMTP compliant email. It is vulnerable to header injection. It may work with some combinations of MTAs and MUAs but please throw this in the bin a get a well maintained, packaged solution like switmailer or phpmailer.

Comment: I know there's a load of issues with this code (otherwise I wouldn't be asking questions) but I'd rather actually learn it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed `return false;` on my button it was submitting before the value could get filled by the `JS`.